# module['test'] isn't equal to module.test?

Tags: python

I'm currently creating a discord bot in which I use the mechanism of modules and I want to access from the modules imported with classes integrated the informations that are set in the beginning of the class. However when i try to go into the module 
https://pastebin.com/ygLAgaWB
and try to access the class into it doing the following "module.help" works but not "module['help']". Since i'm replacing the "**help**" with a variable like : module[var], i can' t use module.var. So how can i solve this problem ? I want to access the 'help' class in the 'module' module using a variable where 'help' is stored in.

I've tried nothing because i don't know what to do.

```py
    module = self.Modules
    var = tmp[0]
    class_ = module[var][var]
```

I expect that it return the class object.

Comment: `a.b` is `a.__getattribute__('b')`, while `a['b']` is `a.__getitem__('b')`. Those are two different methods that don't need to be defined the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Python isn't JavaScript, `module["help"]` and `module.help` are two different concepts. Square brackets take indices or keys, attributes are retrieved with dot notation.

If you need to access an attribute using a variable you can use

```
getattr(module, var)
```